# Using popup blocker enabled, getting a React error Too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, window.open

I have a weird issue..  I am opening a blob returned from a graphql query which is a pdf..  If I enable the browser popup blocker it works as expected, I do get a message in the url bar saying a popup was blocked..  if I set it to allow popups I get 50+ tabs of the pdf and an error messaging saying "Too many re-renders" in the console.

if I remove the "&& closeModal()" from

```
{fileType.includes('pdf') && !isIE && window.open(documentSource) && closeModal()}
```

I get just one pdf opened but the calling page goes blank with a different error message in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
> Window]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

Anyone have a suggestion of what I am doing wrong in the blow code?

```
    const closeModal = () => {
    setLoadingMsg(true);
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Modal
        showModal={showModal}
        onEsc={closeModal}
        onClickOutside={closeModal}
      >
        <StyledModal>
          {documentData && (
            <StyledHeader>
              <StyledHeaderText>
                <Text size="14pt">
                  {documentData.file_name?.replace(/(-?[0-9]+([0-9]+ )?)/g, '')}
                </Text>
              </StyledHeaderText>
            </StyledHeader>
          )}

          {!documentError && (
            <StyledBox>
              {!isIE && (
                <img alt="Loading" src={Loading} width="auto" height="100px" />
              )}
              <Box>{showLoadingMsg ? 'Preparing your document...' : ''}</Box>
            </StyledBox>
          )}

          {fileType.includes('htm') && <Box />}

          {fileType.includes('pdf') && !isIE && window.open(documentSource, "_blank") && closeModal()}

          {fileType.includes('pdf') && isIE && (
            <Box>
              <a href={documentSource}>Download Ready</a>
              <StyledText>
                Please right-click the above link and select <strong>Save target as</strong> to
                download your document.
              </StyledText>
            </Box>
          )}

          {(fileType === 'error' || documentError) && (
            <StyledBox>
              <Text>There was an error fetching the requested document.</Text>
              <Text>Close the modal and try downloading again.</Text>
            </StyledBox>
          )}
          {(fileType === 'error' || documentError || isIE) && (
            <StyledFooter>
              <StyledCloseButton label="CLOSE" onClick={closeModal} />
            </StyledFooter>
          )}
        </StyledModal>
      </Modal>
      <DocumentsPage
        onDocumentClick={onDocumentClick}
        isLoading={loading}
        information={items}
        error={error}
        accountNumber={accountNumber}
      />
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to manage all your pdf logic outside the render, like:

In your return:

```
{checkTileType(fileType)};
```

Add a new function:

```
function checkTileType(type) {
  if (type.includes('htm')) {
    return <Box /> 
  }

  if (type.includes('pdf')) {
    if (isIE) {
      return <Box> ... </Box>;
    }
     
    closeModal();
    window.open(documentSource, "_blank");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I moved most all of the logic out and into a function.. still get the too many re-renders message

Comment: Good be nice if you can create a codepen!

Comment: I created a sandbox, if you set your popup blocker to allow, it will open a boat load of tab's..  Be warned.. https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snyder-h6t73?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Nice, in order to avoid the 'too many re-renders' message you can move `setDocumentSource` and `setFileType` to a `useEffect` hooks like: `useEffect(() => { setDocumentSource("https://www.myairplane.com/Canon_w8400-sm-pc.pdf"); setFileType(documentSource); }, [documentSource]);`. Also move `documentInfo` and `documentError` out of the App component (performance)